# Get all radio inputs from dynamically generated divs

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a series of dynamically generated div that each one has 4 radio buttons inside:

```js
   $(".wrapper").on("custom", ".item", function(){
        $.each($(".item"),function(){
            // Get all radio names and check if at least one is checked
            var radio_groups = [];
            $.each($(this).find('input[type="radio"]'), function(){
                var myname= this.name;
                if($.inArray( myname, radio_groups ) < 0){
                    radio_groups.push(myname);
                }
            });
            console.log(radio_groups);
            return false;
            // Check if there is a radio selected for each radio group
            for(var i=0; i<radio_groups.length; i++) {
                if($(this).find('input[type="radio"][name="' + radio_groups[i] + '"]:checked').length <= 0) {
                    // $('input[type="radio"][name="' + radio_groups[i] + '"]').first().closest('.row').append('<p class="input-error">Please select one option.</p>');
                    $('input[type="radio"][name="' + radio_groups[i] + '"]').first().closest('.condition').append('<p class="input-error">Please select one option.</p>');
                    errors = true;
                }
            }
        })
    })
    $('.item').trigger("custom");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried this but doesn't seem to work, mostly the problem is that the .item divs are dynamically generated with php.

Comment: if you have 4 groups, you have to put 4 different name values. Either you just have only one button checked at maximum among 16 radio..its what you want?

Comment: its not clear, you want to trap name from all radio checked, and whole names are different?

Comment: If they are `dynamically generated with PHP` then Javascript should work OK

Answer (score 0):

I probably didn't understand the problem but why not just use `querySelectorAll` with a simple `forEach` like that:

```js
let result = [];
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((el) =>{
  const radioboxname = el.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')[0].name;
  if(!result.includes(radioboxname)){
    result.push(radioboxname);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_123">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_124">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_124">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_124">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_124">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_125">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_125">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_125">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_125">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_126">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_126">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_126">
        <input type="radio" name="dynamic_name_126">
    </div>
    </div>
```

---

After comment by OP

I add an `array` and instead of select all radios i select all item divs and check the name of first radio button compare with array and include if wasn't include

Comment: The names are dynamically generated, so each one is unique, I do not know the names, that's why I need a way to get all radios from those dynamic divs.

Comment: See now if is result you need, i just change all name of radio

Comment: I am getting this error: VM1142:166 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: It's possible your html is different because as you can see all work here. try to change `document.querySelectorAll('.item')` into `document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > .item')`

Comment: Oh wait I might know the issue, it's on my side. I will try and confirm if it's working.

Comment: Ok, let me know